# Unable to load native components of Sql Server Compact when I try to run my application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have created a setup for c# app. but after installation it shows me following error:

```
Unable to load native components of SQL Server compact corresponding to the ADO.NET 
provider of the version 8080. 
Install the correct version of SQL server compact.
```

Do I need to include SQL Server Compact in my application setup?

Comment: Build 8080 in version 3.5. not 4.0. You are probably referencing the wrong version

Comment: @ErikEJ Add it as answer as it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Build 8080 is version 3.5. not 4.0. You are referencing the wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

please install sql server compact edition.

download from : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

then restart your application, then it should be work.

Comment: I have already installed Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 but it still gives me an error "Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details."